# how to move player by single button press Based on direction rotation of joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Number 1 is the Joystick (work fine)

number 2 is the button needed to press for the Object to move

what is the code to move the object only when the button is pressed and based on the Joystick directions if it sat still or moved?

[image: annotated screenshot of the controls]

Comment: Hey there, it would be useful if you included a code sample of what you already have so people can help you find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be something along the lines of:

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Spaceship: MonoBehaviour
{
  // ...

  ///<summary>rigidbody for the ship for physics</summary>
  public Rigidbody2D rb;
  ///<summary>the force for the thrusters or something</summary>
  public float thrustForce;

  ///<summary>The current joystick input vector</summary>
  private Vector2 _direction = Vector2.zero;
  ///<summary>is the thrusting button held?</summary>
  private bool _thrusting = false;

  ///<summary>in which we obtain the current state of the inputs</summary>
  void Update()
  {
    // ...
  
    // get current direction (normalizing it if the magnitude is greater than 1)
    Vector2 rawDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    // (n^2) > 1 only if n > 1
    // (so we can check the more efficient .sqrMagnitude instead of .magnitude)
    if (rawDir.sqrMagnitude > 1) 
    {
      _direction = rawDir.normalized;
    }
    else
    {
      _direction = rawDir;
    }

    // if you don't care about analog 'not fully tilting
    // the stick in a certain direction' inputs, you can
    // just omit that if statement and make the direction
    // .normalized in all situations

    // and is the thrust button held?
    // Replace "Thrust" with "Jump" to test this using the spacebar.
    // This will need to be refactored in order to use a GUI button.
    _thrusting = Input.GetButton("Thrust");
  
    // ...
  }

  ///<summary>and now we use those inputs for some PHYSICS!!! (wow)</summary>
  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    // ...


    if (_thrusting) // if button is held
    {
      // we add the appropriate thrust force in the specified direction
      rb.AddForce(_direction * thrustForce);
    }

    // ...

  }

}
```

the above code uses the legacy input system, but it should be simple enough to refactor the core logic to work with the new input system in case your project uses that.

Comment: the button is working but it cant register it ArgumentException: Input Button Thrust is not setup.
 To change the input settings use: Edit -> Settings -> Input
UnityEngine.Input.GetButton (System.String buttonName) (at <95f432784b304c859373ab0805d8dfa5>:0)

Comment: Well, I don't know what your button is identified as in your code. Replace that `Input.GetButton("Thrust")` with however you are trying to get the state of your button. Maybe it has a different name in the input manager (in which case, replace the `"Thrust"` with the actual name of it), maybe it's a `Button` component (in which case, add a method to listen to the `clicked` callback and toggle the `_thrusting` attribute appropriately), etc.

Comment: bro I am a Complete noob so hear me out. What its the Input for thrust in the manger? thrust means I can go where ever I want according to my joystick but with add force so I can go Horizontal and Vertical. the code you wrote definitely work I debug it but I couldn't found any way to adress the button

Comment: Okay, for time being, replace the `"Thrust"` with `"Jump"`, and hold the space bar. That will demonstrate it moving. However, **I don't know how you have set up that 'press to Move' button**. If you were to edit your post to state **exactly** how you have set up that 'press to Move' button (could you include a screenshot of the inspector panel view of that button?), I would then be able to show you how exactly to use that button to move the spaceship.

Comment: well, if it works, mark this question as 'solved'.